# Using putty -m option gives 'command not found'

Tags: linux, ssh, putty

If I open a shell into a machine with: `putty -load session_name` and then execute a command to add a job to a Grid queue on a linux system (`qsub -cwd -b hostname`), everything works fine.

But if I add the command to a text file, and then do `putty -load session_name -m file.txt`, I get `qsub: command not found`

If I back out and simplify the text file to be only the command `hostname` and use the -m option, it also works fine.

If I use the Connection->SSH->Remote command, and do something similar as the -m command, I get the same results as from the command line.

I'm very much a novice at linux systems, and this seems like it should be a simple fix to tell something that 'qsub' exists somewhere. Either that or there are some restrictions on these remote access things...

Edit:

Ok, so the initial question was how to run it--and I figured that out (add an absolute path), but there are other environment variable issues as well. It appears that `qsub` requires the `SGE_ROOT` variable to be set, but that isn't set for the remote commands window either.

So, a better question is, how do I get the putty remote commands shell (using -m) to open with the same properties and setup as a manual command line shell?

Answer (score 1):

`qsub` is on your path when you log in interactively, but in the non-interactive shell it is not.  Give the full path in the script, or set `PATH` in the script, and you ought to fix your problem.

It seems you need to run your command in the context of an interactive session, but the `sshd` protocol doesn't directly do that.  So try invoking the command indirectly through `/bin/sh`.

```
/bin/sh -i -c "qsub -cwd -b hostname"
```

The `-i` makes the shell initialize itself like an interactive one, so it will load all the environment variables in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` that are loaded in a real interactive shell.  The `-c` provides a command to run within that interactive shell.

You shouldn't have to explicitly set any paths this way since it works in an interactive session.

Comment: I managed to find that out with the help of a friend. There still seem to be issues with the "command line shell" versus the putty remote commands shell as now I get an environment variable not set error.

Comment: I've edited the question above. I'm using Sun Grid Engine (cluster computing) and it needs a path to the install location set in `SGE_ROOT`. I don't think it is application specific, more along the lines of the difference between the two ways the shell is opened and the initialization and environment variables and such. I just don't know where to dig. It would be great if I could just say, "Use the same settings/setup as the manual shell"

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to be working. I added the commands to a text file and tried it. I get this now:

`Using username "sgeadmin".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
/bin/sh: 0: can't access tty; job control turned off
                                                    /bin/sh: 1: qsub: not found`

Previously:
`Using username "sgeadmin".
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"

              Unable to initialize environment because of error: Please set the environment variable SGE_ROOT.
                              Exiting.`

Comment: `-i` did not have any effect for me. The only thing that worked for me was using `source .profile`.